# Self-Dual Pointclass with a Universal Set?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I'm a little bit embarrassed to be asking this, but I can't find my mistake!
Assume AD. I am going to construct a self-dual pointclass with a universal set, swhich is impossible.

Let A $\equiv_w A^c$ and consider the pointclass $\Delta = \{ B | B\leq_w A\} $. By Wadge, $\Delta$ is a self-dual pointclass. Next, define $U(x,y) \leftrightarrow x(y)\in A$ where we view reals x as coding continuous functions in some reasonable way. The function $(x,y) \mapsto x(y)$ is continuous so $U \in \Delta$ (we have written U as a continuous preimage of A). Also U is clearly universal for $\Delta$, a contradiction.

Can you please help me find my mistake?

Thank you,

Cody

Comment: Are you sure you can achieve $(x,y)\mapsto x(y)$ being continuous? As long as its definition is as handwavy as "in some reasonable way", that looks rather suspect.

Comment: Hi Henning, thanks for your comment. Yes, I am sure I can achieve $(x,y) \mapsto x(y) $being continuous. This is fairly common in descriptive set theory. If you have seen how to use reals to code Lipschitz continuous function, then coding all continuous functions is only a slight generalization.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can define $U$ the way you define it (so that it can be universal in the end), is for $A$ to be $\Delta$-complete set, for some non-selfdual pointclass $\Delta$. (Sorry for using $\Delta$ for non-seldual pointclasses!). So the mistake is in assuming at the outset that $A$ is a $\Delta$-complete set, where $\Delta$ is $\textit{selfdual}$. But since $A\leq_W A^c$ (and in any case $\Delta$ is selfdual in your example), this can't be.

Notice that $A^c$ is a $\Delta$ set, but if $U$ were universal and a section of $U$ realized $A^c$, then this would give, for some $x\in \mathbb{R}$, that if $x(y)\in A^c\leftrightarrow x(y)\notin A \leftrightarrow \neg U(x,y)$, but then $U(x,y)\leftrightarrow x(y)\in A^c$, so $U(x,y)\leftrightarrow \neg U(x,y)$. (but I guess you saw that already...)

So you can't just conclude $U$ is universal unless you secured first that $A$ is a $\Lambda$-complete set for some nonselfdual pointclass $\Lambda$, otherwise the definition is not valid.

Comment: Hey Rachid, thanks for your post. Maybe I'm not seeing it, but I still don't see the answer to my question. Your second paragraph is demonstrating why a selfdual pointclass can't have a universal set- I certainly agree that this is true! However, I still don't see why my example doesn't work. In my example I feel like A IS a $\Delta$ complete set. The whole point is that we're using a self dual pointclass that has a largest wadge degree. It seems like any set of this largest wadge degree will be complete for that pointclass, hence give rise to a universal set.

Comment: You're right the notion of being a complete set can be used in the context of selfdual pointclasses, even though I always attach the notion to non-selfdual pointclasses. Actually I'm not saying things right in the answer. The point is even if $A$ is $\Delta$-complete, $U$ just can't be universal, essentially because $A^c$ is also realized as a section of $U$ by the above definition. This blocks $U$ from even being universal.

Comment: even $\to$ ever in the post above...

Comment: I understand that selfdual pointclasses can't have universal sets. It for the exact reason that you described. I was asking what was wrong with my example.

Answer (score 0):

After a few conversations I figured it out. Henning's suspicion was right. The point is that not all reals code continuous functions (it is true that if x does code a continuous function $(x,y) \mapsto x(y)$ is continuous). So the computation $U(x,y) \leftrightarrow x(y) \in A$ is misleading, U is actually $\exists^\mathbb{R} \Delta$